# Jasmine Unit test case throws error as Cannot read property 'id' of null

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I am writing test case for a method that maps one object to another object that has similar properties.

**user.ts**

```
mapRequest(){
   const common_property =["id","name","age"];
   this.req= {};
   this.userObj = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('userObj'));
   common_property.forEach(item => req[item] = this.userObj[item]);
   this.req.location = "AN";

 }
```

**user.spec.ts**

```
it('should mapRequest called ',done => {

  component.userObj = { "id": "123" , "name":"xyz" ,"age":25}
  component.mapRequest();
  expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  done();
 })

}
```

though i set the value for userObj Object to get mapped to req obj i am getting error as cannot read property 'id' of null. I am learning to write test case so please correct what is wrong here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be logical in your tests, e.g Lets follow your test

1. You set the value of `this.userObj`

```typescript
 component.userObj = { "id": "123" , "name":"xyz" ,"age":25}
```

2. You then call `mapRequest()`

```typescript
component.mapRequest();
```

3. Step 3 above sets the value of `this.userObj`

```typescript
this.userObj = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('userObj'));
```

But the value of `window.localStorage.getItem('userObj')` will be null

4. Now you try to access `this.userObj[item]` which is null hence the error

**Solution**

Try Below

```typescript
it('should mapRequest called ', () => {
  spyOn(window.localStorage, 'getItem').and.returnValue({ "id": "123" , "name":"xyz" ,"age":25})
  component.mapRequest();
  expect(component.userObj.id).toBe(123);
 })

}
```

Comment: spyOn window.localstorage throws error as Argument of type string is not assignable to parameter of type never

Comment: Please check, I have removed the quotes on `'window.localStorage'`